# Numbers at the corner of their bar in a histogram, how can I get them centered under the bar?

Tags: r, histogram, bar-chart

I'm drawing a histogram with the standard hist function with this example dataset:

```
v= c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L,1L,1L,2L, 2L, 2L,4L, 4L, 4L)
hist(v, main='example', xlab='example', ylab='example', breaks=5)
```

The problem that I'm having is that the hist picture looks like this

```
| ___
||   |
||   |___     ___ 
||   |   |   |   |
||___|___|___|___|
 0   1   2   3   4
```

So because the 0 starts at the corner, the 0 and 1 bar are combined, and the bar of 2 and 4 looks like it belongs to 1 and 2, 3 and 4. What I want to have is

```
| 
|   
| ___ ___ ___     ___
||   |   |   |   |   |
||___|___|___|___|___|
   0   1   2   3   4
```

I tried by changing the breaks, but that does not solve the problem of the numbers being at the corner. How can I get the numbers to be centered under the bars?

Comment: Shouldn't the histogram have a bar for 3 as well?

Comment: A histogram is supposed to have the labels at the breaks. The plotted area is the number of values between the breaks. If you want a barplot then use `barplot`.

Comment: @Hudson I accidentaly put the wrong vector in as example, changed it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should use `?barplot` instead.

```
v = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L,1L,1L,2L, 2L, 2L, 3L,3L,3L,4L, 4L, 4L)
barplot(table(v))
```